# Rewrite from x import y statement to use import_module

Tags: python, python-import

I have an existing simple import statement as follows:

```
from booking import Booking
```

Which I would like to rewrite to accept dynamic paramters via the `importlib` library.

My attempts have been variants of the following:

```
from importlib import import_module

mymodule = import_module("Booking", "booking")
```

Which all raise the exception:

> ImportError: No module named Booking

Comment: `booking` is a package or simple module?

Comment: Is `Booking` a class?

Comment: `booking` is a package and `Booking` is a class

Comment: Any luck with trying mymodule = import_module("booking", "Booking")?

Comment: @Damian, putting the package name in first nullifies the specific error, but the contents of the `mymodule` variable becomes a `module` object rather than the `class` object I'm aiming for. Perhaps `importlib` is not the correct library for what I am trying...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this function to import classes dynamically from a module:

```
def import_class(modulename, classname):
    ''' Returns imported class. '''
    try:
        return getattr(__import__(modulename, globals(), locals(), [classname], -1), classname)
    except AttributeError:
        print 'Error in importing class. "%s" has no class "%s"' % (modulename, classname)
        return None
    except ImportError as e:
        print 'Error in importing class: %s' % (e)
        return None
```

Comment: Thanks @Milo. My implementation thus became: `mymodule = import_class("booking", "Booking")` and I'm sure this will be used in many a project to come!